# End time for crontab job

Tags: linux, unix, solaris

I'm going to run snoop command for every 5min during `20:00` till `23:00`, but i don't know how to kill at last 5min (`22:55` till `23:00`). Would you please help me in this regard.

snoop command:

```
FILE=vitrin_`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`.cap
kill -9 `pgrep snoop`
snoop -x0 -d e1000g0 -o /export/home/vitrin/$FILE
```

Crontab:

```
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 20,21,22 * * * /export/home/snoop.sh
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of killing your `snoop` (and possibly some other unrelated ones) from the next cron run, you could just run it from the start under the supervision of a tool such as [`timeout` from coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html). At least under linux you almost certainly already have it, unless your coreutils are pretty old.

```sh
timeout 5m snoop ...
status=$?
[ $status -eq 124 ] && exit 0
exit $status
```

If you really need `SIGKILL` `timeout` has a `--signal` option.

If the running command is killed by timeout the exit status is set to 124. In your case it seems you want to ignore it, eg. like in the example above.

Comment: I just put kill in order to keep the log files in average size.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might help:

```
kill -9 $(pgrep snoop) && \
  test $(date '+%s') -lt $(date -d "23:00" '+%s') && \
  snoop -x0 -d e1000g0 -o /export/home/vitrin/$FILE
```

or like this in the crontab:

```
*/5 20-23 * * * /export/home/snoop.sh
```